# Else method for ifPresent Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I want to know how to do some behavior if some value is not present after filter a stream.

Let's suppose that code:

```
foo.stream().filter(p -> p.someField == someValue).findFirst().ifPresent(p -> {p.someField = anotherValue; someBoolean = true;});
```

How I put some kind of `Else` after `ifPresent` in case of value is not present?

There are some `orElse` methods on Stream that I can call after `findFirst`, but I can't see a way to do that with those `orElse`

Comment: @TagirValeev thanks, it seems that in jdk9 will be a specific method to do that

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`findFirst` returns an `Optional` describing the first element of this stream, or an empty Optional if the stream is empty.

If you want to apply a function when `Optional` is not empty you should use `map`. `orElseGet` can call another lambda if `Optional` is empty E.g.

```
foo.stream()
   .filter(p -> p.someField == someValue)
   .findFirst().map(p -> {
       p.someField = anotherValue;
       someBoolean = true;
       return p;
   }).orElseGet(() -> {
       P p = new P();
       p.someField = evenAnotherValue;
       someBoolean = false;
       return p;
   });
```

Comment: Ok, but if I want to execute an instruction in `orElse`? example, I want to execute `p.someField = evenAnotherValue; someBoolean = false;`
How could I do that with your approach?

Comment: The idea is that if Optional is empty you cannot do anything with it. `orElse` is meant to create a new object of whatever type p is and you can call map on that. I'll update the answer

Comment: Nice, it worked as expected.